# error CS1955: The member 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Action>.Count' cannot be used as a method or delegate

Tags: c#, syntax-error, system

i am using repl.it to program while i am at school. i'm using the same code as i am at home, but getting an error. i'm not sure if i made a tiny mistake that i didn't notice, or what, but i need help. here is my code:

```
  public static void Main (string[] args) 
  {
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

    if (debugMode == true)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("DEBUG ON");
    }
    else if (debugMode == false)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("DEBUG OFF");
    }

    List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();

    actions.Add(() => NormalDay());

    Random random = new Random();

    int selectedAction = random.Next(0, actions.Count());

    actions[selectedAction].Invoke();
  }
```

Comment: `actions.Count`, not `actions.Count()`. It's a property, not a method.

Comment: With `using System.Linq`, however, `actions.Count()` will work and invoke the general extension method. That probably explains the difference between the setups.

Answer (score 4):

Let's go into a bit of detail.

`List<T>` has a property called [`Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.count?view=netframework-4.8). Because it's a property, you access it without using brackets:

```
int count = mylist.Count;
```

There is also an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) on the [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=netframework-4.8) class, which defines a [`Count()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Count__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) method on everything which can be enumerated (i.e. anything which implements [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.8)): this includes `List<T>`. This is called as if it was a method on `List<T>`.

However, the compiler will only find this extension method if you've got `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file.

For example:

```
using System.Linq;

...
int count = mylist.Count();
```

(In the specific case of `List<T>`, the `Count()` extension method will just access the `Count` property, so using either will work. It's more normal to use the `Count` property however).

So the difference is, at school you had `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file, but you don't at home.